# ddrescue overflow

Tags: ddrescue

I am trying to recover a partition on my broken hard disk with this command:

```
ddrescue --r3 --force /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1 logfile
```

- /dev/sda2 is 207 GB and contains the data I need
- /dev/sdb1 is a 270 GB USB hard disk

Now when doing the math, ddrescue ought to be finished at around 212.992 MB (that's 208 GB) but right now it copied 216.721 MB and it is still running.

Is this the right behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to be patient and wait until it finishes, the software may need some extra space to repair broken files or stuff like that. If it does not go to run over your free hdd space, it will be fine.

Comment: Is it possible to break the execution, mount the drive to see if certain files can be copied, and then continue ddrescue later?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know you software, so I do not know that. I suggest you to switch to another console and view the copied files with it.

Comment: Ah sorry - a bit more info: The partition is NTFS and I am running ddrescue from a Linux LiveCD

Comment: What kind of linux do you use on you live cd? Most linux systems allow switching to different consoles by using Ctrl + Alt + (F- keys).

Comment: Well the destination partition is not mounted, and anyway the partition will probably need to be repaired with Windows' chkdsk before any access is possible. I will try it.